# Updating a 2D array inside function

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to update a 2d Array by passing it as a parameter onto a function, but I do not seem to understand how it's been working, I am showing an example below it works correctly, it updates the values.

```
void substitution_sbox(uint8_t a[4][4]) {
      int index1, index2;
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
          index1 = a[i][j] >> 4;
          index2 = a[i][j] & 0x0f;
          printf("index[1]: %x and index[2]: %x\n", index1, index2);
          a[i][j] = g_aes_sbox[index2 + (16 * index1)];
          // g_aes_sbox[] is a globally defined array.
        }
      } 
  }

uint8_t plain_text[4][4] = { {0x32, 0x43, 0xF6, 0xA8}, {0x88, 0x5A, 0x30, 0x8D}, {0x31, 0x31, 0x98, 0xA2}, {0xE0, 0x37, 0x07, 0x34} };
//after calling substitution from here..
// SUBSTITUTION.
    printf("calling substitution\n");
    substitution_sbox(plain_text);
    // this function when printing, updates the array correctly.
```

Now if I try calling the same array inside another function, it does not update as I thought -

```
void row_shift(uint8_t a[4][4]) {
   for(int i=1;i<4;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        // rotate this row by i positions, to the left.
        
        // m = no. of rotations.
        for(int m=0;m<i;m++) {
            // rotate by one.
            uint8_t temp = a[i][0];
            for(int n=0;n<4;n++) {
                a[i][n] = a[i][n+1];
            }
            a[i][3] = temp;
            
            // rotate by one
        }   
        

        for(int g=0;g<4;g++) printf("%04x ",a[i][g]); 
        printf("\n");
     }
   }
}
```

This function does not change the array, the array remains the same, can someone help me understand that how does the update work in both cases?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> how does the update work in both cases?

It is impossible to help you concerning *substitution_sbox* because all is unknown about *g_aes_sbox*

Anyway why are you doing something complicated as

```
  index1 = a[i][j] >> 4;
  index2 = a[i][j] & 0x0f;
  ...
  a[i][j] = g_aes_sbox[index2 + (16 * index1)];
```

rather than

```
a[i][j] = g_aes_sbox[a[i][j]];
```

Because *a* is an array of `uint8_t` the value of `index2 + (16 * index1)` being `a[i][j] & 0x0f + (16 * (a[i][j] >> 4))` is `a[i][j]`

---

> This function does not change the array, the array remains the same

first you have an undefined behavior doing :

```
for(int n=0;n<4;n++) {
    a[i][n] = a[i][n+1];
}
```

when *i* and *n* value 3 you assign `a[3][3]` with `a[3][4]` which is out of the array, the behavior is undefined.

By chance the undefined behavior may have no visible effect, and you cancel the wrong assignments doing after `a[i][3] = temp;`

A right way is to test `n<3`rather than `n<4`.

Out of that your function has no visible effect on the array for the simple reason you rotate each row having 4 values 4 times.

If a rows contains 1 2 3 4, after the first rotation you have 2 3 4 1, after the second 3 4 1 2, after the third 4 1 2 3 and after the fourth 1 2 3 4 which is obviously the initial content

Comment: okay, I get it, sir, this was my first time using uint8_t data type. I was trying to rotate each row by some values to the left, i.e. first row by 0 places, second row by 1 and so on. I messed up the logic I guess.   The g_aes_sbox[] is a 1D uint8_t array containing 256 values.

Comment: The for(int n=0;n<4;n++) was to rotate the array by one position and then the loop just enclosing it is the loop which is repeating it 4 times, so as to rotate the array by appropriate amount.

Answer (score 1):

The array *is* actually being changed in function `row_shift()`, it's just that each row is rotated a *multiple* of 4 times. Beacuse each row is of length 4, the net effect is that the row appears unchanged, i.e.

- Row 0 is not rotated.
- Row 1 is rotated 4 times (4*1).
- Row 2 is rotated 8 times (4*2).
- Row 3 is rotated 12 times (3*4).

The first nested loop

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    ....
}
```

is the problem, I think. Remove that and you should find that the rows are rotated 0, 1, 2 & 3 times respectively.

Further to that there is the bug identified by [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518372/21945) where there is out of bounds access on the array. You must fix that too.

Comment: Thank You so much, I get the logic now.